# Django rest framework is returning 'u prefix to angular from the database

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

I am using the Django Rest Framework and Angularjs to create a site that takes information for hair stylists and saves it to a database. There is another page that pulls that information from the database and displays it on a profile page.

The problem I am having is that it is returning the unicode prefix 'u when I call that data and javascript wont let me work with that.

This is what I get back:

```
{"stylist":"{u'email': u'chris@internet.com', u'profession': {u'esthetician': True, u'hair_stylist': True}, u'name': u'Chris', u'certification': u'no'}","created_at":"2015-05-04T19:27:19.482058Z","updated_at":"2015-05-04T19:27:19.511937Z"}
```

My model:

```
class StylistSubmission(models.Model):
    stylist = models.CharField(max_length=2500, null=True, blank=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.stylist
```

My serializers.py:

```
class StylistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StylistSubmission
        fields = (
            'stylist',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')
```

My views.py:

```
class StylistViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = StylistSubmission.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    serializer_class = StylistSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        instance = serializer.save()
        post_save.send(sender=self.__class__, stylist=instance.stylist)
        return super(StylistViewSet, self).perform_create(serializer)
```

I've been banging my head against a wall for a few days now trying to figure this out. I am new to the django rest framework and very new to angular so I may be missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is not the `u`, it's that for some reason you have a Python dictionary rather than JSON. (Note also the single quotes).

Comment: Any Idea how I can not get the python dictionary back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the intended separation of concern, I'd suggest leaving the  perform_create function to focus on "saving" the model.

The create() function (from the CreateModelMixin parent) is the function that has responsibility for generating the HTTP response, so that'd be the better place to render and emit the response, right?

```
    from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        return Response(JSONRenderer.render({'stylist': serializer.data}), status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

PS: Typically a RESTful endpoint will just emit the Stylist object, rather than wrapping it inside another key ('stylist'). Since it's the response to a create POST, it's implied the object returned will be a Stylist object.